# How to create a 16b grayscale image in java

Tags: java, image-processing

I am working on encryption of grayscale images in java. I have have performed DCT on a grayscale image which has resulted in high energy coefficients like 372, 356, etc in different 8X8 block of the images. Since these values cross 255, I cannot write the DCT values to a 8b grayscale image, so I want to know how to write the DCT values to 16b grayscale image in java?

Answer (score 0):

To create a 16 bit grayscale in Java, you can create one using the standard `BufferedImage` constructor:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY);
```